# OpenLayers Hide/Show Layers from external checkboxes

Tags: openlayers

I'm using OpenLayers with mapserver to display a lot of raster images and queryable wms layers. Everything works fine, the layers can be turned on/off in the OpenLayers layer switcher...But now I want to turn on/off the layers by external checkboxes and I don't know how to do this.

I'm little bit new to Javascript-the only thing I know is that I have to pass the checkbox layer value to an OpenLayers function. Till now I tried to call a function with an onClick event

`<input type="checkbox" name="ckeckbox_layer1" onClick="layervisibility(this.checked);">`

But I don't know how the function 'layervisibility' has to look like so that my layers that are actually placed in the openlayers init() function turn on/off correctly when I check/uncheck the checkboxes.

Answer (score 14):

#### OpenLayers 2:

[`layer.setVisibility(true)`](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.setVisibility)

#### OpenLayers >= 3:

[`layer.setVisible(true)`](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_layer_Base-BaseLayer.html#setVisible)

Lots of examples here:  http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/

Specific example: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/layer-group.html